# Django + Docker + SQLite3 How to mount database to the container?

Tags: django, sqlite, docker, mount

I had sqlite database with some sort of tables on my localhost and i wanted to copy and paste that database to my server which runs on docker. I created paths like this:

[image]

**db_data:** there is my sqlite database which i want to run in my django project.
**web:** there is my whole django project

in my docker-compose.yml i writed this volume:

```
version: "3"

services:

  web:
    build: ./web/
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    volumes:
      - ./web:/code
      - /home/cosmo/db_data/db.sqlite3:/code/db.sqlite3
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
```

So i thik that docker will get database in my db_data and will make volume inside my web folder (in my project. There i had database on my localhost so it wouldnt be problem.) But i will paste here **settings.py**:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

So when i will open my db.sqlite3 inside db_data every tables and content are there, but when i will run container the db.sqlite3 in my project folder (web) is empty.

When i will run docker ps command there is no database container maybe this is the problem i dont know. I have there only:

[image]

in the red circle is my django container. So when i will run my server and try to login every account from the database is unknown. So I think that container works with that empty db in my project. Someone please has any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Using sqlite like this sounds like a bad idea. Why not have a proper db - Postgres or MySQL - in another container?

Comment: because i have all the data in there and it will be very painful to migrate to another database. also i have everything setup for this. I know that all tutorials are for postgres, but i want to figure out this.

Comment: You'd need to add the database to a volume, or burn it into the image

Comment: and it is not in the volume?

Comment: @idature have you got the solution for your problem?
'jrtapsell' could you tell the what is the solution if I want to check same thing for sample POC work;

Comment: There's nothing wrong with SQLite, but don't copy the db into the container, just map a volume, otherwise your DB vill vanish when the container comes down!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. BASE_DIR will be the folder of the settings file, which generally is in a folder at the root. So likely you have a directory issue. If you can move the file directly into the same folder as the settings.py you can at least eliminate those variables.
2. You won't see a container, its just binding a volume, which you should also make unique so don't nest it like you have `/code/db.sqlite3` but put it in its own folder then you can reference that in your settings file. You could see list of volumes using `docker volume ls` (assumes Docker 1.8+)